# ndiswrapper installed wireless driver, but fails to load driver - couldn't prepare driver 'netrtwlane'

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I have a new model of wireless module from Realtek - RTL8723DE in an HP 15-BS576TX laptop (2017 June launched) which is not yet supported natively in Linux. The driver may be available in another few months as per rtlwifi maintainer as he awaits Realtek to release sources.

So, I thought of trying luck with ndiswrapper for this RTL8723DE WiFi module, though, ndiswrapper project appears to be rather stagnant.

I can load ndiswrapper and even it lists netwrtlane as installed. But, Wireless module is not detected and configured, neither seems to be working with the Windows 7 64-bit driver that I used with ndiswrapper.

The driver is provided by HP for Windows 7/8/8.1/10 versions. I used Win 7 64-bit driver after extracting the executable. I even made sure to copy all the available files to be inside a single folder, in case, if that helped. Ndiswrapper says driver is installed.

```
:~$ ndiswrapper -l
netrtwlane  :  driver installed
        device (10EC:D723) present
```

But, the driver is not loading - the syslog is here: http://pasted.co/a293d2d1

```
kernel: [ 1755.786026] ndiswrapper (load_sys_files:200): couldn't prepare driver 'netrtwlane'
kernel: [ 1755.786509] ndiswrapper (load_wrap_driver:103): couldn't load driver netrtwlane; check system log for messages from 'loadndisdriver'
kernel: [       1755.786577] usbcore: registered new interface driver ndiswrapper
```

Besides, the syslog shows "unknown symbol: NDIS.SYS" "unknown symbol: WDFLDR.SYS".

Is this Windows 7 driver has any possibility to work with ndiswrapper?

I checked the realtek page and for their Windows drivers, it is written that:

```
**RTL8723BE/RTL8821AE/RTL8822BE/RTL8821CE/RTL8723DE: WLAN/Bluetooth combo solutions, need to install WLAN and Bluetooth drivers**
```

Kernel version: 4.13.0-17-generic

Answer (score 0):

Unofficial Linux driver for RTL8723DE module available here: https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de

You have to build the module (8723de) and modprobe it to work.